# Automatically arrange XML Elements according to XSD Schema in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, xsd

Is there a way for me to arrange XML Elements automatically according to XSD Schema using Oracle SQL?
I am generating an XML file from Oracle and the output looks like below:

```
  <tns:SprzedazWiersz>
    <tns:LpSprzedazy>5</tns:LpSprzedazy>
    <tns:KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>BB</tns:KodKrajuNadaniaTIN>
    <tns:NrKontrahenta>43815678</tns:NrKontrahenta>
    <tns:NazwaKontrahenta>Business World</tns:NazwaKontrahenta>
    <tns:DowodSprzedazy>48</tns:DowodSprzedazy>
    <tns:DataWystawienia>2016-11-01</tns:DataWystawienia>
    <tns:DataSprzedazy>2016-11-30</tns:DataSprzedazy>
    <tns:B_MPV_PROWIZJA>1</tns:B_MPV_PROWIZJA>
    <tns:EE>1</tns:EE>
    <tns:I_63>1</tns:I_63>
    <tns:TP>1</tns:TP>
    <tns:K_10>.05</tns:K_10>
    <tns:K_11>.3</tns:K_11>
    <tns:K_12>1</tns:K_12>
    <tns:K_14>3.35</tns:K_14>
    <tns:K_17>.22</tns:K_17>
    <tns:K_20>2</tns:K_20>
    <tns:K_30>5</tns:K_30>
    <tns:K_31>4</tns:K_31>
  </tns:SprzedazWiersz>
```

The Error Message points to `tns:EE`:

> Cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid Content Was Found Starting With
>   Element 'tns:EE'. One Of
>   '{"http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":DokumentZakupu,
>   "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":MPP,
>   "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":IMP,
>   "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":K_40,
>   "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":K_42,
>   "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":K_44,
>   "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":K_45,
>   "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":K_46,
>   "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":K_47,
>   "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2020/03/06/9196/":ZakupVAT_Marza}' Is
>   Expected., Line '202', Column '13'.

Based from the XSD, below are the sequence of Elements:

```
<xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Oznaczenia dotyczące procedur</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:element name="SW" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Dostawa w ramach sprzedaży wysyłkowej z terytorium kraju, o której mowa w art. 23 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="EE" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Świadczenie usług telekomunikacyjnych, nadawczych i elektronicznych, o których mowa w art. 28k ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="TP" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Istniejące powiązania między nabywcą a dokonującym dostawy towarów lub usługodawcą, o których mowa w art. 32 ust. 2 pkt 1 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="TT_WNT" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Wewnątrzwspólnotowe nabycie towarów dokonane przez drugiego w kolejności podatnika VAT w ramach transakcji trójstronnej w procedurze uproszczonej, o której mowa w dziale XII rozdziale 8 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="TT_D" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Dostawa towarów poza terytorium kraju dokonana przez drugiego w kolejności podatnika VAT w ramach transakcji trójstronnej w procedurze uproszczonej, o której mowa w dziale XII rozdziale 8 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="MR_T" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Świadczenie usług turystyki opodatkowane na zasadach marży zgodnie z art. 119 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="MR_UZ" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Dostawa towarów używanych, dzieł sztuki, przedmiotów kolekcjonerskich i antyków, opodatkowana na zasadach marży zgodnie z art. 120 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="I_42" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Wewnątrzwspólnotowa dostawa towarów następująca po imporcie tych towarów w ramach procedury celnej 42 (import)</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="I_63" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Wewnątrzwspólnotowa dostawa towarów następująca po imporcie tych towarów w ramach procedury celnej 63 (import)</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="B_SPV" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Transfer bonu jednego przeznaczenia dokonany przez podatnika działającego we własnym imieniu, opodatkowany zgodnie z art. 8a ust. 1 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="B_SPV_DOSTAWA" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Dostawa towarów oraz świadczenie usług, których dotyczy bon jednego przeznaczenia na rzecz podatnika, który wyemitował bon zgodnie z art. 8a ust. 4 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="B_MPV_PROWIZJA" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Świadczenie usług pośrednictwa oraz innych usług dotyczących transferu bonu różnego przeznaczenia, opodatkowane zgodnie z art. 8b ust. 2 ustawy</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="MPP" type="etd:TWybor1" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Transakcja objęta obowiązkiem stosowania mechanizmu podzielonej płatności</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Is there a way for me to store the XSD in the Database and reference it when arranging the XML? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexPoole The XSD uses [xsd:sequence](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_sequence.asp) so yes, order does matter. You can [validate your XmlType against the XSD](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/transformation-and-validation-of-XMLType-data.html#GUID-45DAA30E-3F14-4D70-8105-ED3855B92A50), but offhand I don't know of an easy way to transform invalid XML into valid XML based on the XSD. You might have to write an XSLT to do it.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I didn't read that properly then. The error still doesn't seem to match the posted XML fragment though. I'll walk away from this one though...

Comment: @AlexPoole, when i re-arrange the elements manually, the error goes away. I was thinking how to handle this programatically.

Comment: See [this similar question for how to rearrange your nodes with an XSLT Identity Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305258/rearrange-xml-nodes-including-sub-nodes-by-xslt). You could add the "xslt" tag to this question if you want to try that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tough problem in the general case, where the schema defines an arbitrary content model. But if you know that the content model is going to be a simple `xs:sequence` like this, then it might just be tractable. For example, you could extract from the schema a list of elements like this

```
<xsl:variable name="ordering">
    <elem name="SW" index="1"/>
    <elem name="EE" index="2"/>
    ...
</xsl:variable>
```

and then you could sort your data in XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="data">
  <xsl:sort select="number($ordering/elem[@name=local-name(current())]/@index)"/>
  ....
</xsl:for-each>
```